# Apply a frame to an image

Tags: .net, wpf, image

I have two images, one of them is like a frame (image that has a custom border and transparent background) and I have another image, I need to apply/merge these two images to show the second image with the frame.

I have seen different examples but I cannot find a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: But them on top of each other in a Grid?

Comment: Joe, I have two images control, I'm not using a grid, but if I need to use them I dont have problem, my case y like some popular photos app, take add photo and next select a frame and merge

Comment: Are they `png` and the same format?

Comment: yes, both images are png Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to overlap components in WPF is simply have both items in a Grid, occupying the same 'cell' in the order you want them to display:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="D:\photo.png"></Image>
    <Image Source="D:\frame.png"></Image>
</Grid>
```

This will show them like this:

[image]

However, this is only overlaying them in the the UI of the application - if you want to, say, save/export these images its a different operation involving image processing/rendering. Although you could render the Grid component to an image.

Even if that's the ultimate goal, it could be more efficient to display them like the above while the user is 'picking' a frame, as it'll be fast an efficient - then properly process the image to render them together when the user presses the 'export' button.

Edit: To render two images into one, try using `Graphics` from `System.Drawing`:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(photo))
{
    g.DrawImage(frame, x, y)
    g.Save();
}
photo.Save(...);
```

Depends on your requirements.

Comment: Joe, I will try, yes, after that I need to get the merged image to save it, or well, to convert it to a stream